# Using MSChart in .net environment within a service

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, service, mschart

Is there any way to use .NET's MSChart from within a service (WCF / restful services) ? The requirement is that a service should be hosted that generates charts and returns the chart image to the calling application.  The calling application shall call a web service method.  There is no web page to embed the MSCHART control.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the chart in code, then save the chart to a stream.  Then return the stream to the caller.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456181.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VB version..

```
<WebMethod()> _
       Public Function GetChart(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal width As Integer) As String
          Dim ch As New Charting
          Dim ds As DataSet = blablabla
          Dim page As New Page()
          Dim form As New HtmlForm()
          form.Controls.Add(ch.buildChart(param1, ds, width))
          page.Controls.Add(form)
          Dim textWriter As New IO.StringWriter()
          HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, False)
          Dim htmltxt As String = textWriter.ToString
          Return Regex.Replace(htmltxt, "<[/]?(form)[^>]*?>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End Function
```

used like (jquery):

```
function GetChart(param1) {
      var params = new Object();
      params.param1 = param1;
      params.width = $(window).width() - 115;
      $.ajax(
      {
         type: "POST",
         data: $.toJSON(params),
         url: "WebService.asmx/GetChart",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         complete: function (response) {
         },
         success: function (response) {
        $(divChart).html(response.d);
         .
         .
         .
```